# Two を in a single sentence - how to understand it?

Tags: grammar, particle-を

In the book I'm reading (「キッチン」 by 吉本{よしもと}ばなな) I have found the following sentence:

> うしろで雄一がぞうきん**を**手に床をふいてくれていた。

I guess it can be translated to something like (sorry for a quite literal translation): "Behind (me) Yuuichi was wiping the floor with a cloth using his hands".

This sentence has two を. One of them (床をふいてくれていた) I understand as marking the direct object (floor) of the verb (wipe).

I cannot understand what the other を is doing there (ぞうきんを). What meaning does it have? What grammatical pattern is used in here?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You usually can't have two をs in one clause, so when you see one, most commonly one of the following is true:

1. It's part of a 〜を〜に（して） construction in which して is left out.

   > AをBに　→　AをBに（して）

   You can recognize this one by the distinctive 〜を〜に pattern, often with a comma.
2. A repeated verb has been left out ("backward gapping"):

   > XがAを、そしてYがBを買った　→　XがAを(買い)、そしてYがBを買った

   Unlike English, in Japanese the *last* verb is retained rather than the first.
3. The を links to a verb in a subordinate clause.

   > Aを [ BをCして ] Dする

   If you see two をs in a row like this and they don't seem to suggest the same verb is coming up, it's usually a signal that the speaker has started a subordinate clause.  Each を links to a different verb.

In this case, I suppose it's probably #1:

> うしろで雄一が　**ぞうきんを　手に(して）**　床をふいてくれていた。

Yuuichi was wiping the floor *with a cloth in his hand*.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure on the meaning based on 1. If I'm understanding correctly; A = ぞうきん、　B＝手, so that we have:  ぞうきんを手にして, meaning; he made the cloth his hand? usually thats what the AをBにするstructure means as far as I know...

Comment: @Pootan: "手にする" is a set phrase meaning (1) to hold (in one's hand); to take (into one's hand) (2) to own; to obtain. It has nothing to do with "to make somthing".