# can を particle be used twice

Tags: particle-を

First of all I wish to say: "I forgot about eating steak."
Is it possible to use を in this sense:

> ステーキを食べるのを忘れた。

Is this correct and if so does it translate to what I want to say?

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/16288/two-を-in-a-single-sentence-how-to-understand-it/16289#16289

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally を cannot be used twice in the same sentence, but here ステーキを食べる is a relative clause nominalized by の.  So, the two を are not in the same sentence.