# Why is the particle を used without a verb in the following context?

Tags: particles, particle-を

First of all, this question shares the same context with [another Q&A asking for the meaning of 手{て}かがり](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/100375/32952).

What follows is an excerpt from N2新完全マスター, in particular the section 問題紹介 where they are explained the different exercises that appear in the N2 Japanese Language Proficiency Test:

[image]

I have trouble understanding the following sentence:

> 【例題3】では「〜について」「〜に対する」という文法形式**を**手がかり**に**、その前後にどんな言葉がくるかを考えます。

Where is the verb corresponding to the highlighted particles を and に? It sure can't be 考えます because it takes another を.

Finishing the relative clause adverbially with 手がかりに feels incomplete and abrupt. I found [this related Q&A](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/20854/32952) where they explain that sometimes the verb is omitted in the construction AをBに, but this sentence doesn't seem to fit the typical examples with body parts and such listed in the [accepted answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/20854/32952).

Is して implied here, as explained in the [alternative answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/20855/32952) of the same Q&A, or what is going on?

> 【例題3】では「〜について」「〜に対する」という文法形式**を**手がかりに[**して**]、その前後にどんな言葉がくるかを考えます。In the example 3, [**make a hint of**] the grammar forms について and に対する, and think of what word comes before and after them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What about these particles](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/51987/what-about-these-particles) / [Meaning of ~を~に(して) / ~を~として / ~を~にする / ~を~とする / ~を~にした / ~を~とした](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/73082/5010)

Comment: It's not limited to body parts. The question you mentioned is linked from [more than 30 related questions](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/20854?lq=1) about this.

Comment: wow thanks, I didn't know you can check the relationships between questions, that's a very helpful trick.

Comment: While I understand that it's not limited to body parts, I find it hard to see how the structure A を B に translates to "with A in/on B" in this case. "With について and に対する in hints"...? I'll take a look to the other posts though.

Comment: The first linked post definitely answers my question, it totally makes sense to interpret it as "with A as B", i.e." taking について and に対する as clues".