# Double を of the form [noun] を [noun] を [verb-stem] つつ

Tags: particles

I have the following from [here](https://matcha-jp.com/jp/6267):

> 本記事｛ほんきじ｝では、最新｛さいしん｝の**築地｛つきじ｝情報｛じょうほう｝を写真｛しゃしん｝を交｛か｝えつつ**、築地｛つきじ｝でオススメの寿司｛すし｝レストラン、軽食｛けいしょく｝や朝｛あさ｝ごはんが食｛た｝べられる店｛みせ｝、また訪日｛ほうにち｝客｛きゃく｝向｛む｝けツアーやアクセス情報｛じょうほう｝などをご紹介｛しょうかい｝します。

By context, I understood it as

> In this article, while providing the most recent pictures and information about Tsukiji market, ...

but I'm not too sure how the grammar works. I've referred to [another post on double を](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/16288/two-%E3%82%92-in-a-single-sentence-how-to-understand-it), which suggests that I might parse the phrase as

> 築地情報を[ 写真を[して] ]交えつつ

Yet, I would think that if 交えつつ refers to two nouns, it would be through the と particle instead, so

> 築地情報**と**写真を交えつつ

Is this another common double-を pattern that's different from what was listed in the linked post?

Comment: 「軽食や朝ごはんが食べられる[店]{てん}」 → 「～食べられる[店]{みせ}」って読みます

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This 交えつつ is not かえつつ but [まじえ](https://jisho.org/word/%E4%BA%A4%E3%81%88%E3%82%8B)つつ. まじえる means something like "to mix/intersperse", and you can say 冗談を交えながら話す ("to talk with jokes"), 雑談を交えつつ会議は進んだ, etc. Here 写真を交えつつ means "using some pictures as well" on its own, and it adverbially modifies 紹介します.

The rest of the sentence is *broken*. 紹介します somehow has two を-marked objects, namely "最新の築地情報" and "築地でオススメの寿司レストラン、軽食や朝ごはんが食べられる店、また訪日客向けツアーやアクセス情報", but this is ungrammatical in standard formal sentences, just as リンゴをバナナを食べる is wrong. I guess this sentence was initially 最新の築地情報を(写真を交えつつ)ご紹介します, which was perfectly fine, but the writer messed it up while trying to augment it.

最新の築地情報**と**写真を交えつつ doesn't make sense, either, because that would make the sentence like 築地情報を交えつつ築地情報をご紹介します, which is nonsense. The AをBに construction is not relevant either because there is no に.

The corrected version would be:

- 本記事では、写真を交えつつ、築地でオススメの寿司レストラン、軽食や朝ごはんが食べられる店、また訪日客向けツアーやアクセス情報などの最新の築地情報をご紹介します。
- 本記事では、最新の築地の写真を交えつつ、築地でオススメの寿司レストラン、軽食や朝ごはんが食べられる店、また訪日客向けツアーやアクセス情報などをご紹介します。