# Two を and one verb

Tags: particle-を, parsing

I'm reading Fairy Tail manga and I don't understand why there are two を in this sentence.

> この我輩を主人公に本を書かせてやると言ったのに、あのバカ断りおった。

If I understood correctly the context, the person who said that sentence made someone else to write a book about him because he used the causative-form of 書くtwice (there is another sentence earlier). Also, I just read that "てやる" means "to do for".

*Is the first を denoting the subject while the second is denoting the direct object?*

After reading "[Two を in a single sentence - how to understand it?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/16288/two-%E3%82%92-in-a-single-sentence-how-to-understand-it)", I thouht the sentence I wrote above could have a different meaning because of the second item in this [を defition](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%82%92) of jisho.org, that is, the first を could be a subject, as in が.

Comment: The subject of this sentence is indeed 我輩 but it is *implicit*. The full version would be 「\[我輩は\]\[お前に\] **我輩を主人公に** 本をかかせてやると言った」. "\[I\] said \[I\] would allow \[you\] to write a book **with *me* as the protagonist**".

Comment: In the example in the dictionary, 声 is the subject of とどく (not とどかせる). 我輩 cannot be the subject of 書く here. This (also linked from the question in the link) is related: [Causative Form - Difference between 子供に本を読ませる　and 子供を本を読ませる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33510/43676)

Comment: "because of the second item in this を defition of jisho.org" Jisho is talking about how things are naturally translated into English, because we don't always think about parts of speech the same way. But を is still a direct object. We might turn the を-marked noun into a subject when translating into English, because the words we want to use for the overall meaning work in a grammatically different way.

Comment: Looking over the example: the structure is more like "about me, within the classroom, the act of [me] causing my own voice to be heard was not possible." 自分の声 is を-marked because it's the direct object of とどかせる; the subject is implicitly 私.

Comment: Well it's way easier to accept the question as duplicated instead of answering many comments here because soon I'll get a message like "why don't you use the chat?". Thanks, buy I'm still confused.

Comment: 本を書かせてやると言った already means "I said I'd let him write a book" (note that I've already supplied the implied personal pronouns, "I" and "him"). **この我輩を主人公に**本を書かせてやると言った means "I said I'd let him write a book **with me as the protagonist**". The added part (bold) is a simple [`AをBに` construction](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/73094/5010) that means "with A as B".